# NIntegrate producing SetDelayed::write message

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I used `NIntegrate` to calculate an integral with the final limit as a variable, which later will be listed in a table,

```
C[a_?NumberQ] := 
  C[a] = (5ΩmQ)/2 (H[a]/H0) NIntegrate[1/(x H[x]/H0)^3, {x, 10^-5, a}];
lst6 = Table[{a, C[a]}, {a, 0.1, 1, 0.05}];
```

The above is just to show how I wrote the proccess.

The problem is, function `H` has several sets of values, and the integral must be calculated for each one. So I wrote the same code for each case in the same notebook (copy-paste). For the first and second set of values inside `H`, the integral is calculated. The third one yields

> SetDelayed::write: Tag C in C[a_?NumberQ] is Protected. >>

I changed the label of the "symbolic integral" `C[a_?NumberQ]` for each set, say `A[a_?NumberQ]`,`B[a_?NumberQ]` and `C[a_?NumberQ]`. The problem is in the last case. `H` function is not changed, I mean it is `H` in all three cases.

Whats is the meaning of the error message?

Comment: Do I have to use something like `Quit` at the end of each case?

Comment: C is a protected symbol from Mathematica: "is the default form for the i^th parameter or constant generated in representing the results of various symbolic computations"

Comment: In general, you should avoid using variables with an uppercase initial letter (camel case is fine) to avoid conflicts like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that `C` is a reserved system symbol.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html

Since `C` has the attribute `Protected`, no further definitions can be made for it.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html